# passar parametros actionlink para função jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Como eu faria para passar parâmetros de um ActionLink de um grid pra uma função jquery?

Esse é o ActionLink:

```
 gridPortfolio.Column( format: @<text> @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteData", new {id = item.CD_PORTFOLIO, par = "PO"}, new { @onClick =  "deleteData()", @class="ActionImgD" })</text>)
```

e essa é a função:

```
function deleteData(params) {//conteudo}
```

Comment: Você vai querer continuar fazendo a requisição depois ou só javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode concatenar os parâmetros na hora de criar o `ActionLink`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteData", 
                 new {id = item.CD_PORTFOLIO, par = "PO"}, 
                 new { onclick = "return deleteData('" + item.CD_PORTFOLIO + "', 'PO');", @class="ActionImgD" })
```

Outra opção é utilizar os atributos `data-*`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteData", 
                 new {id = item.CD_PORTFOLIO, par = "PO"}, 
                 new { onclick = "return deleteData();", 
                       @class="ActionImgD",
                       data_cd = item.CD_PORTFOLIO  /* isso aqui */
                     })
```

Que vai gerar um atributo `data-cd="seuvalor"` na tag.
Pra recuperar:

```
function deleteData() {
    var cd = $(this).data('cd');
    //...
}
```

Comment: Deu mais ou menos certo aqui, o primeiro parametro ele esta passando isto `+item.CD_PORTFOLIO+` como string e não esta pegando o valor do meu grid  ja o segundo esta passando certo. Estou usando da seguinte forma `gridPortfolio.Column( format: @<text><input type="image" img src="~/Content/Image/excluir.png" onclick="return deleteData('+item.CD_PORTFOLIO + ', 'PO')" /></text>)`

Comment: Você esqueceu de fechar as aspas duplas `"` antes e depois do `+`. Correto seria colocar algo como:  `(' " +item.CD_PORTFOLIO + " ',`

Comment: coloquei dessa forma, mas agora deu Unteminated String constant Expected ')'. tenho problema em colocar estas aspas. hahahaha.

Comment: esta desta forma agora: `onclick="return deleteData('" +item.CD_PORTFOLIO + "', 'PO')" /></text>)`

Comment: Com essa forma deu erro? Tenta com o data-*